# How can i make the logo not getting over the fixed navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i make the logo not getting over the fixed navbar? as you see in the image the logo gets over the fixed navbar. How can i make the div not get effected by the fixed navbar? Is there anyway you could make it just not go over the navbar.below you see the image when the logo is infront of the navbar.
[image]

```css
.content {
      width: 94%;
      margin: 4em auto;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
      line-height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      margin: 16px 46px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
      line-height: 60px;
      list-style: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding-right: 40px;
      transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
      background: #fff;
}

nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-icon {
      line-height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      display: none;
}
.slide-right {
    display: block;
    left: 30%;
 right:50%;
 top: 25%;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
         animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
   }
   .image-desc {
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 17%;
       right:50%;
    position: absolute;
       top: 55%;
    color: #fff;
   }
  .image-desc h1 {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #555;
 -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
         animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
   }
```

```html
<header>
                  <nav>
                        <div class="menu-icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo">
                             <img src="/TeknikSnabben/assets/image/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu">
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">TJĂ„NSTER</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                  </nav>
        <div class="slide-right" >
     <img src="/TeknikSnabben/assets/image/logo2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="image-desc"><h1> VI HJÄLPER DIG MED DIN TEKNIK I HEMMET </h1>
                  </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `nav` a higher z-index and a background-color:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 4em auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 46px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #fff;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  ;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.slide-right {
  display: block;
  left: 30%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

.image-desc {
  width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 17%;
  right: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  color: #fff;
}

.image-desc h1 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #555;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: slide-right 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/80/80">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">START</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TJĂ„NSTER</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="slide-right">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  </div>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <h1> VI HJÄLPER DIG MED DIN TEKNIK I HEMMET </h1>
  </div>  
</header>
```